# A Hash that finds results that are close

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

I have a table that has about 10000 entries each entry has almost 100 boolean values.  A user checkboxes a bunch of the booleans and hopes to get a result that matches their request.  If that record doesn't exist, I want to show them maybe 5 records that are close(have only 1 or two values different).  Is there a good hash system or data structure that can help me find these results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitmap indices. Google for the paper if you want the complete background, it's not easy but worth a read. Basically build bitmpas for your boolean values like this:

```
010110101010
110100010100
000101001100
```

And then just XOR your filter through them, sort by number of matches, return. Since all operations are insanely fast (about one cycle per element, and the data structure uses (edit) 100 bits of memory per element), this will usually work even though it's linear.

Addendum: How to XOR. (fixed a bug)

```
000101001100 source
000101001010 target
000000000110 result of XOR

 int n = 0; if (v) do { n++; } while (v &= (v-1)); return(n);
```

The two 1's tell you that there are 2 errors and m-2 matches, where m is the number of bits.

Comment: not one cycle per element, it's an XOR then you count the 1s. Though with only 10000 entries this is still a good idea.

Comment: Pipelining does that for you, and you could theoretically optimize the assembly code down to that point. I know I have done that in an exercise at university at some point. And if it it takes 2-3 cycles: A 1 Ghz CPU offers one billion cycles a second. ;)

Comment: it's not 4 bytes per element either. it's 12 or more.

Comment: Pipelining doesn't mean that you have less instructions to do. It means the instructions you do do take less time. The instructions are: add a constant to a counter, do a lookup (which is more than one instruction because of address space translation), XOR a few times, count ones (this is more than few instructions even using a lookup table), do comparison, then either add to list or move to next. It's still a good idea, it's just not as few instructions as you seem to think.

Comment: How would one determine the number of matched flags using a XOR operation?

Comment: Most of these instructions can (and will be) executed in parallel, therefore only taking up a single cycle. XOR for 64 bits (at least) is a single instruction, and completely independent of the address space translation (the i++, as it were). See 3.15 here: http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf

Comment: only on itanium. the instructions will be executed serially, however preparations for the next instructions will commence before the current instruction has finished. No instruction will take less than a cycle.

Comment: but the entries are more than 64 bits, it will take at least 2 cycles for a complete xor.

Comment: this is just splitting hairs. I like your idea, but it's a dozen or so instructions for each comparison.

Comment: Not familiar with bit wise operations, what does the &= do? And what does V represent, the entry that is being compared to the search?

Comment: and doesn't XOR give a 0 for 0 XOR 0?

Comment: I fixed that. All the 0's and 1's were the wrong way around. That doesn't change how it works, only how the result is interpreted. v &= a means v = v & a. I recommend reading up on bitwise arithmetic, it's sometimes useful, and not actually difficult.

Comment: The value you pass in, e.g. 000000000110. It's C/C++ which means that if(v) will return true if it is not equal to 0. http://www.custard.org/~andrew/programming/bitwise/

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is a **nearest neighbor search**: based on a record, find the 5 closest records based on an arbitrary distance function (such as the number of different values).

A hashing function intentionally discards any information except "these values are equal", so it's not really the way to go.

Consider using instead a data structure optimized for nearest neighbor searching, such as a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) or [vp-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP-tree). If there's a high probability that a record already exists in the list, you could first use a hash table to look for it, and then fall back on the kd-tree if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

This builds on the answer from Kdansky.

```
Create a dynamic array of entries.
Create a cache.

for each lookup,
   check the cache.
   return the cache entry if the value exists.
   otherwise for each value in the dynamic array,
       if hamming distance is less than threshold add to the result list
   cache the value against the result
   return the result
```

to find the hamming distance:
xor and find the hamming weight http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight